# Build expression interactively

Tags: dynamic

I define two lists:

```
atoms = {"p", "q", "a", "b"};
operators = {Defer@Plus[Placeholder[], Placeholder[]], 
             Defer@Times[Placeholder[], Placeholder[]], 
             Defer@Max[Placeholder[], Placeholder[]]};
```

Now I would like to build the expression `a + b Max[p, q]` by starting with an empty placeholder and then click and select the entries from the lists above.
The first step would be to click the empty placeholder and select the `Plus` operator; next, click the first new placeholder and select `a`, then click the second placeholder and select `Times` and so on.

I started with the code below which doesn't work. Any suggestions ?

```
DynamicModule[{expr = \[SelectionPlaceholder]},
   EventHandler[Dynamic[expr], 
    {{"MouseClicked", 1} :> ( expr = expr /. {\[SelectionPlaceholder] ->     
       ListPicker[{}, Join[operators, {Delimiter}, atoms]]})}]]
```

Comment: I've create a room but I don't know how inviting works :) So here's the link: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20907/kuba-b-gatessucks